# How can I compute the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the indefinite integral of the following function:
$$
\int{\mathrm{d}x \over \,\sqrt{\,\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(7x\right)\,}\,}
$$

And how can I compute this ?.

Comment: They are different because this is $cos7x$, not $cos^7x$ @lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee They're not the same. Is there a way you could undo the marked duplication?

Comment: I thought that was a typo

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this has a closed-form solution?  I strongly suspect it does not.

Comment: It is an exercise in a textbook, but actually, I'm not sure about whether it has. @RobertIsrael

Comment: Anyway, let $u=tanx$ or $u=tan2x$ may work, but this is still complicate.

Comment: It's very unlikely to have an elementary solution.

Comment: It can result in a 7th degree polynomial denominator. I guess such an integral is already there on MSE.

Comment: WolframAlpha can't integrate it.